# Java BinarySearch program

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, search

I am learning Java programming and made a program which uses **Binary Search** to find a **symbol** in an **array of char**. However, I have a problem when I try to search for the **symbol** which is **not** in an **array**, my program becomes an endless cycle. I have no idea how to make an error sign if there is no such symbol in an array. Here is the code of my program

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        char[]arr = {'a','d','f','l','o','z'};
        find(arr,'m');

    }
    public static void find(char[]arr,char ch){
        int last = arr.length-1;
        int mid=last;
        while (arr[mid] != ch){
            if (arr[mid]<ch){
                mid = (last+mid)/2;
            }
            else{
               last=mid;
                mid=last/2;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(mid);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Stepping through the debugger to find what is not changing. Note: if `mid == last/2` this won't change anything.

Comment: You are implicitly assuming that the index of the lower bound of your search is always 0. Please check a description of "binary search" in any good textbook or on the internet.

Comment: @PeterLawrey It seems that `last=mid` before `mid=last/2` avoids "won't change anything". But not having a `first` ruins performance.

Answer (score 0):

You have no case to break out of the while loop and the changed values assigned to the variables during the 2 if cases are incorrect. Plus, you should also check for when the element is found in the if-else ladder and use a variable (found) to indicate whether the element is found. Moreover, it'll be better if you use 3 variables for the lower bound (first), mid and upper bound (last). The code below is a revision of the find() method.

```
public static void find(char[]arr,char ch){
    int first=0,mid=0,last=arr.length-1,found=0;
    while (first<=last){
        mid=(last+first)/2;
        if(arr[mid]==ch){
            System.out.print(ch+" found at index "+mid);
            found=1;
            break;
        }
        else if(arr[mid]<ch){
            first=mid+1;
        }
        else if(arr[mid]>ch){
           last=mid-1;
        }
    }
    if(found==0)
    System.out.print(ch+" was not found ");
}
```

This works fine and maybe you should use this method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make some changes in your `find()` method.First check that the value of `mid` should never exceed the value of `last`,so you have to change your while loop condition accordingly. Secondly you have to give a terminating condition `if(arr[mid]==ch)` to come out of the loop.
This can also be done by using two variables `lo` & `hi` ,easy to understand & implement.See the implementation here [Binary Search](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/11model/BinarySearch.java.html).

Below is the solution using only only `last` & `mid` variables,as per your code requirement above:

```
public static void find(char[]arr,char ch){
        int last = arr.length-1;
        int mid=last/2;
        while (mid<=last){
            if(arr[mid] == ch) //if found, Print and exit the loop
            {
                System.out.println("found at:"+mid);
                return;
            }

            if (arr[mid]<ch){
                mid=((last+mid)/2)+1;
            }
            else{
                last=mid-1;
                mid=last/2;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Not found!!");
    }
```